# Find out the path to the addon folder in the Thunderbird API

Tags: thunderbird, thunderbird-addon

I am modifying an addon for thunderbird and found the path to the addon hardcoded in one of the javascript files. This seemed sloppy to me and I thought that it had to be possible to find out this path programmatically. However, after much googeling, I still can't find an answer to that question.

Do you know how I can find out the path to the folder (containing the `install.rdf`) of a Thunderbird addon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`AddonManager` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Addons/Add-on_Manager/AddonManager) for that:

```js
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm");

AddonManager.getAddonByID("foo@example.com", function(addon)
{
  var uri = addon.getResourceURI("install.rdf");
  if (uri instanceof Components.interfaces.nsIFileURL)
  {
    var file = uri.file;
    alert(file.parent.path);
  }
});
```

For reference: [Addon](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Addons/Add-on_Manager/Addon), [nsIFileURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIFileURL), [nsIFile](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPCOM_Interface_Reference/nsIFile).

The assumption in the code above is that the extension is unpacked upon installation, your predecessor probably added [`<em:unpack>true</em:unpack>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Install_Manifests#unpack) to `install.rdf`. Normally this flag shouldn't be specified, leaving the extension packed on disk is better for performance. If you simply need to read a file from your extension you can use `XMLHttpRequest` for that without requiring that it is a physical file on disk:

```js
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm");

AddonManager.getAddonByID("foo@example.com", function(addon)
{
  var uri = addon.getResourceURI("example.txt");
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest("GET", uri.spec);
  request.addEventListener("load", function()
  {
    alert(request.responseText);
  }, false);
  request.send();
});
```

Comment: One thing though: I need to run a python script, so the second piece of code doesn't really work for me. But still, it's a start and I will look into that. Thanks again.

Comment: @janoliver: Yes, if you want to run code then you either have to get the extension unpacked or you have to copy the Python script into a temporary directory first.